# Add a class with value/range 0 (N/A) to a chloropleth map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, classification

I am trying add a class whose range is basically less `<=` zero or `N/A`. I have to add `6` classes (Natural Breakdown) from the `Age_30_49` column and add the seventh one manually somehow without chaning anything in the first 6 classes. Part of the problem is that this column does not have a `0` value so, I don't know how to add the 7th class without chaning the ranges of the first `6` classes.

How can I do this in `ArcMap 10.8`?

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing a manual classification? "n/a" is not a valid internet value, but it is for legend text

Comment: Yeah you see the ranges in the screenshot above are from the "Natural Breakdown"  classification method. So I guess I can use "manual classification" and define the first 6 classes as given by natural Breakdown and have the 7th one as zero. And then label the 7th class as N/A.

Comment: @Vince, let' say I convert the legend to graphics, is there then a way to add a 7th class with that white striped symbol box and label it NA in ArcMap?